# urllib2 having trouble processing colon symbol in url

Tags: python, urllib2

I am using the API for challonge and their url format is `https://username:password@challonge.com/api/`.

However, when I use urllib2 in python to get this url

```py
response = urllib2.urlopen('https://username:password@challonge.com/api/')
```

I get an error about a non-numerical port number.  I believe this is caused by the colon (:) in the url making urllib2 think i'm trying to get a port of something.

Is there anyway around this issue, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you must use auth handlers like urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler or other.
[urllib2 docs](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html)