# Error in urllib2 but not in urllib (Windows only)

Tags: python, windows, urllib2, urllib

I've coded a python script to update a dynamic IP in dyndns.org. Dyndns needs a petition like:

```
"http://"+dyndns_user+":"+dyndns_pass+"@members.dyndns.org/nic/update?hostname="+dyndns_host+"&myip="+ip
```

I was using urllib to process the request and it worked OK:

```
dyndns = "http://"+dyndns_user+":"+dyndns_pass+"@members.dyndns.org/nic/update?hostname="+dyndns_host+"&myip="
dyndns_update = urllib.urlopen(dyndns+newip)
dyndns_msg = dyndns_update.read()
```

But I read that urllib is *Deprecated since version 2.6* in favor of urllib2, so I tried it:

```
dyndns = "http://"+dyndns_user+":"+dyndns_pass+"@members.dyndns.org/nic/update?hostname="+dyndns_host+"&myip="
dyndns_update = urllib2.urlopen(dyndns+newip)
dyndns_msg = dyndns_update.read()
```

The problem is: If I execute latter code in Linux works OK, but in Windows I obtain a URLError exception because apparently, urllib2.urlopen() is trying to parse the ":" in dyndns string as url port (and fails). If I execute former code (using urllib) the script works OK both in Linux AND Windows.

Anybody know what's happening? I believe that it's probably my fault, but the fact that the script works in Linux but not in Windows bothers me...

Comment: Read this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696999/urllib2-having-trouble-processing-colon-symbol-in-url/9697147#9697147)

Comment: Thank you, That was exactly my problem.  I think I'll keep using urllib cause it's easier and I don't need extra features in urllib2.

Comment: Yes. In the new version they are a bit complicated.